# Pandas read csv just get 1 column

Tags: python, pandas, csv

the code here,I dont see anything wrong

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\eric.zhai\Desktop\gls_测试_10.11.csv',sep='\t')
print(df)
```

but the output is:

```
      11.11.11.11,109395,Host name of zabbix_agentd running,agent.hostname,28875,11.11.11.11:agent.hostname.diff(0)}>0,Host name of zabbix_agentd was changed on {HOST.NAME},1,0
0   11.11.11.11,109396,Agent ping,agent.ping,2887...                                                                                                                           
1   11.11.11.11,109397,Version of zabbix_agent(d)...                                                                                                                           
2   11.11.11.11,118235,java进程15109 zookeeper-3.4....                                                                                                                           
3   11.11.11.11,118236,java进程15223 zookeeper-3.4....                                                                                                                           
4   11.11.11.11,125177,java进程15820 nc.bs.mw.start...                                                                                                                           
..                                                 ...                                                                                                                           
218 11.11.11.11,109434,Free disk space on $1 (per...                                                                                                                           
219 11.11.11.11,109436,Total disk space on $1,"vf...                                                                                                                           
220 11.11.11.11,109438,Used disk space on $1,"vfs...                                                                                                                           
221 11.11.11.11,109421,Available memory,vm.memory...                                                                                                                           
222 11.11.11.11,109422,Total memory,vm.memory.siz...                                                                                                                           
[223 rows x 1 columns]
```

expectd:[223 rows x 13 columns]

why?MY csv file was broken?can u help me with it? just get 1 column...

Answer (score 0):

you have passed `'\t'` as delimiter when it should be `','` - use either the default delimiter or comma as your delimiter

`pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\eric.zhai\Desktop\gls_测试_10.11.csv')`

or

`pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\eric.zhai\Desktop\gls_测试_10.11.csv',sep=',')`

Comment: I tryed ,but:      pandas.errors.ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 9 fields in line 22, saw 14

Comment: are you able to paste the first 23 rows of your data?

Comment: Thank you.I tried this.it worked.  I added  'error_bad_lines=False'
        ```df=pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\eric.zhai\Desktop\gls_测试_10.11.csv',error_bad_lines=False)```